# Oracle date between list of min max dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of fish cought at different dates.

table landings:

```
Long ID, 
Long Vessel_id, -- vessel that is fishing 
TimeStamp fishing_date, 
double amount_cought
Long species_id;
```

Next there is a table of companies using the vessels to fish.

table ves_usage:

```
Long ID,
TimeStamp usage_start_date,
TimeStamp usage_end_date,
Long vessel_id,
Long using_company_id;
```

Lastly i have a table of licences to fish specific species for a company during a given year.

table licences:

```
Long ID,
int year, --the year that the lincence is active
Long licenced_company_id,--company who was given the licence
Long species_id; --species that the company can fish
```

I'm trying to select all the records from landings table that have a specified species, company, and vessel. The problem I have is i cant think of a way to select all the landing records that are in between Start and End date of ves_usage table records. Not sure if im clear enough :P
I want to make something like:

```
Select * 
from landings 
where fishing_date between <list of usage_start_date and usage_end_date from ves_usage table>
```

Comment: You need to do a join. (Or have lots of OR BETWEEN.)

Comment: Sample data and especially desired results would make it clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So do you want all the landings ever done by a specific company (using `using_company_id`) or all the landings done during a specific trip (using `id` from the `ves_usage` table)? ALso, you gave us the `licences` table; is there anything you want done with that?

Comment: say i have a licence for Company_A for fishing during the year 2006.
theres a Vessel_A that was used like this:
2005.01.05 - 2006.03.04 used by Company_A
2006.03.04 - 2006.07.03 used by Company_B
2006.07.03 - 2008.01.01 used by Company_A.

i need all the landing that were during the periods of Company_A usage and the specified licence year

Comment: @mindz Okay, but is it relevant to the query you are attempting, and if so, how?  And do you want the query to be based of of the `ves_uasage` ID column, or the `using_company_id`?

Comment: I, too, have problems understanding how the `licenses` table comes into play. You know what company caught what amount of what species at what day (and hence year) by looking at `landings`and `ves_usage` only. Are you trying to limit your results to only which was *legally* fished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am following your tables correctly I believe the query would be something like:

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM landings l
     JOIN ves_usage vu
          ON vu.vessel_id = l.Vessel_id
          AND l.fishing_date BETWEEN vu.usage_start_date AND vu.usage_end_date
     JOIN licences li
          ON li.vessel_id = vu.Vessel_id
          AND li.species = l.species_id
WHERE l.fishing_date = /*date here*/
      AND li.licenced_company_id = /*company id here*/
```

Comment: The query ended up something like that. Just for some reasom a regular JOIN fetched all the data still. When i moved the join to FROM ... WHERE... the data was selected properly

Answer (score 0):

If you want the query to be based on `ID` from `ves_usage`, this query will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM landings 
WHERE fishing_date BETWEEN
  (SELECT usage_start_date FROM ves_usage WHERE id = <id from ves_usage>)
  AND
  (SELECT usage_end_date FROM ves_usage WHERE id = <id from ves_usage>)
```

If you want something different, please specify, as requested in the comments.